# Что означают красные точки в редакторе сниппетов?

Tags: поддержка, сниппеты

Редактирую [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/99747/181472), переношу код в сниппет. В окне с кодом HTML вижу какие-то красные точки. Это не символы текста, удалить их не получается. Структура HTML вроде бы не нарушена, по крайней мере выравнивание кода по отступам этого не показывает.

Что эти точки означают? Должен ли я как-то отредактировать код и добиться, чтобы точки пропали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это просто Utf-8 символы `zero-width space \u200b` Их можно удалить.

Comment: @vp_arth точно. С нескольких попыток смог их вычистить. Не хотите ответ написать?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это просто Utf-8 символы [zero-width space \u200b](http://www.charbase.com/200b-unicode-zero-width-space).
Если навести на них курсором мыши - вы увидите всплывающую подсказку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Их можно удалить.

Comment: Скриншот всплывающей подсказки вообще непросто делать. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin притскрин всего экрана, потом обработать в редакторе)

Comment: @pavel, у меня по нажатию кнопки `PrnScr` пропадают тайтлы(из-за потери фокуса). *Upd: хотя, раз через два вроде ловит =)*

Comment: Кстати, вы фанат кубика Рубика?

Comment: Не фанат, но собирать умею, минуты за три)

Comment: @NickVolynkin утилиты для снимка экрана умеют "замораживать" весь экран перед выполнением снимка даже какой-то части. [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/), например, такой.

Comment: @alexolut у меня проблема в том, что при нажатии Ctrl, Shift, Alt или Cmd всплывающая подсказка пропадает. Для запуска утилиты наверняка понадобится какой-то из этих ключей.

Comment: @NickVolynkin неа. Там жмется PrintScreen, всё замораживается, потом выбирается область мышью и вуаля, скриншот готов. То есть по сути он внутри себя делает полный скрин и позволяет сразу обрезать.

Comment: @alexolut ну и для Greenshot мне ещё сменить ОС понадобится. )) Но в целом выглядит неплохо. Если когда-нибудь приспичит, буду искать что-то похожее.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я думаю специализированные проги все должны такое уметь. Просто как пример привел то, чем пользуюсь. Может Вам просто надо найти соответствующие настройки.

Comment: @alexolut разобрался, как штатными средствами ОС сделать. Просто нужно зажать нужные ключи (Cmd+Shift), **потом** навести курсор и дождаться подсказки. Дальше как обычно — 3 для полного экрана, 4 для рамочки. )

Comment: @alexolut *блин, опять мою программу кто-то другой написал*...

Comment: А ещё такие скриншоты можно делать с задержкой. Программа **gnome-screenshot** умеет делать снимки экрана после указанного интервала, за который можно успеть подвесть курсор мыши и дождаться всплывающей подсказки